# Cast Fluent Aggregate Query Result to type in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2 I have a query like this:

```
$query = DB::table('myTable')
->select('name', DB::raw('SUM(var) as sumofvar')
->get();

dd($query);

// returns:
//
// array(
//   "name1" => ".66",
//   "name2  => "1.32", //etc
// )
```

This runs OK but the `sumofvar` in the result is returned as a string rather than a float/decimal. The column is a decimal in MySQL.

Currently I have to `array_map` or similar to convert each value to a numeric. Is there a way to have Fluent get a numeric result from an aggregate fuction?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

When you select data from a MySQL database using PHP the datatype will always be converted to a string. You can convert it back to float using the following code:

```php
$sumofvar = (float) $row->sumofvar;
```

Or by using the function [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```php
$sumofvar = floatval($row->sumofvar);
```